# Revmob crashing my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, banner, revmob

I'm generating a banner in a tableview with revmob, which seems to be the one that crashes my app. The crash happens while navigating in and out several times to the tableview that contains the banner, using 3g.
I generate it this way in viewDidLoad, in a view I prepared for it:

```
//Revmob banner
RevMobBannerView *ad = [[RevMobAds session] bannerView];
ad.delegate = self;
self.banner.delegate = self;
[ad loadAd];
[ad setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
[self.tableView addSubview:ad];
```

This is the crash:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs perfectly when in a "normal" view (ex: scroll view). Just check your third code line

```
self.banner.delegate = self;
```

because there is no reference here for `self.banner`.

The problem should be with your table view controller.

Here is RevMob website for more information: https://www.revmobmobileadnetwork.com

Comment: self.banner is an IBOutlet to an UIView reserved for displaying the banner. It is defined, and the code compiles and runs fine.